# Javascript array Filter to use external function result

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var data = [];

data.push({
  Id: 1,
  name: "ONE"
});
data.push({
  Id: 2,
  name: "TWO"
});
data.push({
  Id: 3,
  name: "THREE"
});

data.filter(function(item) {

  if (item.Id == 1) {
    return item.name = display();
  }
});

function display() {
  return "Formatted Text";
}
```

I am using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)array `filter` function to find a value inside [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)array of objects. I am not able to use `display()` function inside this filter.

Compiler keeps telling `display()` function is `undefined`.

Comment: filter returns an array with the filtered items. you need an assignment and just return the result of the check.

Comment: @NinaScholz could u pls demonstrate?

Comment: You have other issues  in code shown but no reason that `display` would be undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), because [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array with the filtered items.

It looks like, you want to assign a new value with a condition, so you need no new array.

```js
function display() {
    return "Formatted Text";
}

var data = [{ Id: 1, name: "ONE" }, { Id: 2, name: "TWO" }, { Id: 3, name: "THREE" }];

data.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.Id === 1) {
        item.name = display();
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Alternatively, he can [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) an item by ID and then update the returned item (if any).

Answer (score 1):

I think you better need to use `findIndex` instead of `filter` like:

```
const arrIndex = data.findIndex(function(item) {
   return item.Id==1
});

if(arrIndex !== -1) { data[arrIndex] = display(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [{
    Id: 1,
    name: "ONE"
}, {
    Id: 2,
    name: "TWO"
}, {
    Id: 3,
    name: "THREE"
}];

data.map(function(item) {

    if (item.Id == 1) {
        item.name = display();
    }
    return item;
});

function display() {
    return "Formatted Text";
}
```

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Instead of forEach just I have used map function. filter will filer the data so here map is preferable